# How to add with to border UITextField Swift when when create Rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to create a rounded corner "Oval shape" UITextField. I have a problem with the inner border is not rounded and give strange log to the UITextField when the background of the UITextField same as the view

How border looks:

[image: how border look like]

Image from the MockAUp what I want to achieve:

[image: Image from the MockAUp what I want to achieve]

Swift code:

```
txtfEmail.layer.cornerRadius = 26
txtfEmail.clipsToBounds = true
txtfEmail.attributedPlaceholder =  NSAttributedString(string: "Email",
                                                      attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)])
```

email UITextfield inspectere

[image]

Comment: Show the code you used to add the border.

Comment: I don't have any code to add border

Comment: Then why is there a border in the first picture?

Comment: I don't know where is that annoying border set  I am sure is not from controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to create a custom `UIView` class with an embedded text field.

Here's an example, using `@IBInspectable` and `@IBDesignable` to let you see it during Storyboard design:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RoundedTextField: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var placeholder: String = "" {
        didSet {
            textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder,
                                                                 attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)])
        }
    }

    let textField: UITextField = {
        let v = UITextField()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        layer.masksToBounds = true

        addSubview(textField)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            ])

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.height * 0.5
    }

}
```

Result in Storyboard / Interface Builder:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this it works for me 
open storyboard 
drag and drop textfield
ctrl click and create an outlet in view controller and name it lets say emailfield
then write this code

```
@iboultet weak var emailfield: uitextfield!{
didset{
emailfield.layer.masktobounds = true
emailfield.layer.cornerradius = 26
emailfield.layer.borderwidth = 1
emailfield.backgroundcolor = whatever color you want
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the rounded border like this:

```
txtfEmail.layer.cornerRadius = txtfEmail.height / 2
txtfEmail.layer.borderWidth = 1
txtfEmail.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

Looks like the border is set to the view under the text field